# Can a Synthesist use the Skilled evolution while fused?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, summoner

The synthesist gains access to the eidolon’s special abilities and the eidolon’s evolutions.

The synthesist eidolon has no skills or feats of its own.

> Evolution **Skilled** (Ex): An eidolon becomes especially adept at a specific skill, gaining a +8 racial bonus on that skill.

The question is, while synthesist cannot use his fused eidolons skills and feats, would he be able to gain +8 racial bonus on a skill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a Synthesist can us the Skilled Evolution while fused.

The synthesist gains access to evolutions, but no skill ranks or feats. This evolution does not give skill ranks or feats. It just happens to give a bonus to a skill, which is quite different.